# Fastest way to simulate multiple given multiple probabilities in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of probabilities `p = [p1, p2, …, pn]`.

All I want is to simulate a list `s = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, …, 1]`, whose first element is `0` with probability `p1` and 1 with probability `1 - p1`, and then so on for the next elements, always matching the corresponding probabilities in the `p`-list.

Currently my solution is to `for-loop` over `p`, and then append to `s` the output from `np.random.choice()` called on each individual `pn`.

```
s = []
for item in p:
    s.append(np.random.choice([0, 1], p=[item, 1 - item]))
```

Comment: Can you add your current solution as code, not as a description of the solution? Preferably as a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to draw your numbers and *element-wise* compare them with your p.
just decide if for `1` you want `>` or `>=`

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([0.2, 0.5, 0, 1.0, 0.9, 0.3, 0.1, 0.8])
x = np.random.random(size=p.shape)
ans = (x>p).astype('int')

print(p)
print(x)
print(ans)


[0.2 0.5 0.  1.  0.9 0.3 0.1 0.8]
[0.08990063 0.51804083 0.9049705  0.0885368  0.1273564  0.18583925
 0.51488052 0.23258143]
[0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0]
```

Comment: Ah yes, using the uniform distribution. Thank you.